# Why does this PHP function give a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV)?

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I wrote the following code.

```
<?php
function f(){
  return f();
}
f();
```

and get the output

```
$ php test.php
Segmentation fault
```

Why? I didn't use any pointers.

This is StackOverflow ?

Comment: `f` calls `f` calls `f` calls `f` calls `f` calls `f` calls `f` calls ... I'd scream segmentation fault too.

Comment: I'd scream "*Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!*" or "*PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in Command line code*".

Comment: Doesn't `xdebug` impose the limit of 100?

Comment: @TomcatExodus, yes, it does. Anyway, without xdebug, I get the second error message about exhausting allowed memory size. Using 5.3.5, both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a case of infinite recursion, but that is not specifically the cause. It is a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). When you have recursion, whether infinite or not, there is a max amount of depth you can recurse (add to the stack) which is based on the size of your stack (in bytes).

Technically this is infinite, but you won't get any errors for quite a while:

```
<?php
function f(){
  sleep(1);
  return f();
}
f();
```

What you need is known as a `base case` in your recursion in order to stop it before it consumes the entire stack.

```
<?php
function f($i){
  if($i == 10)
    return;

  echo $i;

  return f(++$i);
}
f(0);
```

Which will print 0 to 9.

The `segmentation fault` error is coming from the operating system, reporting the PHP application has encountered an issue adding to the stack. That won't make it to your script because at the system level the binary which makes up PHP has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that an infinite recursion? What're you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it is an infinite loop. Definitely PHP will report error.

Comment: yeah. that's right . but the SIGSEGV is only occur on C/C++ code? isn't it?

Comment: @freddiefujiwara: PHP is written in C and PHP is segfaulting here.

Comment: @freddiefujiwara: Yep, there you go ... mu gave us the ans :)

Answer (score 1):

This comes specifically from the XDebug extension.

Running GDB, you will see:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff41f7e48 in xdebug_add_stack_frame (zdata=Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff5fefa8
) at /build/buildd/xdebug-2.1.0/build-php5/xdebug_stack.c:772
772 /build/buildd/xdebug-2.1.0/build-php5/xdebug_stack.c: No such file or directory.
    in /build/buildd/xdebug-2.1.0/build-php5/xdebug_stack.c
```

If XDebug is disabled, it will execute until the `memory_limit` is reached. If your `memory_limit` is too high, you might exhaust RAM and start swapping, freezing/crashing your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion you've set up continues to add stack frames until you overrun the amount of memory assigned to the PHP process call stack, at which point you get a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion).