# PHP Built-In Server Exiting with SIGSEGV / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, infinite-loop, segmentation-fault

Developing a wordpress blog locally, my PHP server is dying with SIGSEGV half-way through rendering the page.

Here's my startup script: `sudo php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t ../reece-blog-local`

I wish I could provide more details, but I can't seem to get any information out of PHP about this. The only reason I know it's exiting with SIGSEGV is that I'm running this process with foreman, otherwise the process just exits silently.

There does not seem to be a particular line of code that's making it break, I can track down the area of the error based on the HTML that's managed to render before exit, and I can stick in a few `echo "Hello, world!"`s  and it breaks on any given one of them.

Notes:

- server was working fine until I upgraded to Mavericks, so thinking that something there could be interfering.
- confirmed this happens when CURLing any URL, so likely rules out this being an issue with serving static files.
- not exhausting my memory limit

How can I further debug this issue, in lieu of any specific errors output by PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP server will exit with segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) error [in the event of infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327607/why-does-this-php-function-give-a-segmentation-fault-sigsegv?rq=1), e.g.:

```
function test() {
    test();
}
```

If the output is buffered and you use `echo` to debug an error like this, the error may appear to occur in strange places (hence why it would seem to break on a line like `echo "Hello, world!";`)

Instead, you can use `error_log($yourMessage, 4);` to output a message to the console. This helped track down the error for me (though from reading around it seems [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) may be the preferred solution for finding errors like this.)

For what it's worth, here's effectively how I had infinite recursion:

```
class TheParent {
  public function __call($method, $args) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);
  }
}

class TheChild extends TheParent {
  protected function thisIsOkay() {
    echo 'yay';
  }
  private function sigsegv() {
    echo 'no';
  }
}

$c = new TheChild;
$c->thisIsOkay();
$c->sigsegv();
```

If we attempt to call a private function in TheChild, __call will be invoked, attempt to access the private function, invoking __call, etc.